# Expo eject from managed to bare not working

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, expo

I created an app with expo using the managed workflow, but I now want to eject it so I can build an IPA for IOS. After running expo eject and following the prompts for pod install, when I try to build the app and view it on the simulator in xCode, I get stuck on the splash screen which results in a *very* long list of errors (attached the relevant looking one below).

Have I missed a step here? I tried looking on the expo documentation but it’s very lacking in using the eject command. Is there a step or something I’m meant to modify after the eject has occurred?

Error: Exception    NSException *   "expo-updates must be configured with a valid update URL or scope key."

Comment: Can you at least show us a part of the error ? We can't just guess

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this by following these steps after I ejected: https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-updates/

And also adding the below to the Expo.plist file in the MyApp/Supporting folder with the below:

```
<key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
<string>https://example.com</string>
```

Comment: Just wondering, did you eject just to make IPA? Do you know with expo build:ios command you can do the same?

Comment: That required a paid dev account and all I want to do is export this as an IPA so i can test it natively on my phone outside of the expo app. However using xcode 12 thats proving to be an issue lol

Comment: No this isn't the case anymore. Now you can make iOS build even if you dont have the a dev paid account. You see. that paid account is used for priority builds. It is for those who cant wait in the turtle queue.

Comment: Do you know how to go about this? Every tutorial I see says to Archive it however it errors out saying i need to select a profile (which expects a paid account)

Comment: Yeah. Just create a simple developer account. No need to buy any subscription. Run command expo build:ios -t
. For more details visit https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#if-you-choose-to-build-for-ios

Comment: Unfortunately the resources linked there arent available unless I pay for a development account